# Failed to run your Python code 'str' object has no attribute 'copy' in Zapier

Tags: python, python-3.x, zapier

I faced with a problem in Zapier. I have an Error "Failed to run your Python code 'str' object has no attribute 'copy' in Zapier", but in the VSCode everything works just perfect.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
import re
import requests
import json

# Email for search
email_to_search  = (input['Email'])

# AMOcrm
subdomain = 'DOMAIN'
user_login = 'LOGIN'
api_key = 'API'

# Parameters for authorization
params = {'USER_LOGIN': user_login, 'USER_HASH': api_key}

# URL for company search by email
company_search_url = f'https://{subdomain}.amocrm.ru/api/v4/companies?query={email_to_search}'

# Request execution
response = requests.get(company_search_url, params=params)

# Check response status and company search
if response.status_code == 200:
    company_data = response.json()
    companies = company_data.get('_embedded', {}).get('companies', [])
    if companies:
        company_id = companies[0]['id']

        # Check response status and company search
        company_info_url = f'https://{subdomain}.amocrm.ru/api/v4/companies/{company_id}?with=leads'

        # Request execution
        company_info_response = requests.get(company_info_url, params=params)

        # Checking the response status and displaying company information
        if company_info_response.status_code == 200:
            company_info_data = company_info_response.json()

            # Obtaining information on related leads
            related_leads = company_info_data.get('_embedded', {}).get('leads', [])
            if related_leads:
                # Getting the ID of the last lead
                last_lead_id = related_leads[-1]['id']
                
                # Formation and output of a link to the last lead
                last_lead_url = f"https://{subdomain}.amocrm.ru/leads/detail/{last_lead_id}"
                print(last_lead_url)
            else:
                last_lead_url = ("No related leads found")

        else:
            last_lead_url = (f"Error in fetching company info: {company_info_response.status_code}")

    else:
        last_lead_url = ("Company not found")
else:
    last_lead_url = (f"Error: {response.status_code}")

output = last_lead_url
```

Checking the Zap settings in Zapier: I looked at the Zap settings in Zapier. This included making sure the field names were correct and matched the data expected in the code.

Fixing bugs in the code: I scrutinized my code and corrected errors I found, such as an error in the field names that were specified in the code, and made sure that the code was correctly extracting and processing data.

Checking for other issues: Despite all efforts, the error "Failed to run the Python code 'str' object has no attribute 'copy'" remained unresolved. I verified that the data was in the correct format and the settings in Zapier were correct, but the error continued to occur.

Comment: There's no `copy` anywhere in the code you posted.

Comment: `input['Email']` is wrong, it should be `input('Email')`. You obviously didn't copy the code accurately.

Comment: Yeah, there's no way this code "works just perfect" in vscode...

Comment: giving the whole error might be helpful to debug. Because you are not calling `.copy()` on any `str` here. So, this might be happening somewhere behind your code.